# Magento error after first step in checkout

Tags: php, magento

When customers go to the checkout of our webshop, it's impossible to go to the second step. The user gets an error.

The same error occurs when we change the checkout to one page checkout.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAllItems() on a non-object
>   in /.../app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 841

It's Magento 1.7.0.2 with all necessary security patches installed.

Someone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: As this is not related to some actual coding (you should at very least show the code of /.../app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php around the line 841), you should probably ask this at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead